How to fix password replay or playback in nodejs
i'm hashing the the user password using bcrypt and stored it into DB.
during login i encrypt password in front end and decrypt it before compare using crypto-js and compared password with bcrypt.compare(), it will allow to login the user when its true.
the above will fine, i stucked in the scenario where user login with same encrypted password many times their password replay will occure how to fix it.
hash the password and sotreit into db
exports.changePassword= function(data, callback){
   bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, (err, salt)=> {
       if(err){
         return err
       }
       bcrypt.hash(data.new_pass, salt, function(err, hash) {
          /////db query
          return db.query('update user set password=?,password_flag=1 where user_code=?'
          , [hash,data.user_id], callback);
      });
   )}
}

login code
var log = require('../logger')
var error = require('../models/error');
const encryptDecryptService = require('../services/encryptDecryptService');

exports.loing = function(data, callback) {
   const passwordData = encryptDecryptService.decrypt(envConfig.ConfigParams.CYPHER_KEY.DECRYPT_KEY, req.body.password);
   const password = passwordData.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
   query = 'Select r.officer_code, r.password, r.name, r.district_code, r.subdistrict_code,  from user r where r.officer_cude=?';             
   db.query(query, [data.user_id], function(err, rows) {
      if (typeof rows[0] != 'undefined') {
         bcrypt.compare(password, rows[0].password, function(err, result) {
             if (err) {
                 error.saveError(JSON.stringify(err), '/login/login');
                 log.error(err);
                 return callback(err,{status: false});
            }
            if (result) {
               db.query('Insert into login_history(ip_address, user_id, user_type) values ("' + data.client_ip + '",' + rows[0].officer_code + ',' + data.usertype + ')', function(err, rows1) {
                  const JWTToken = jwt.sign({
                     username: rows[0].name,
                     _id: rows[0].officer_code,
                     usertype: rows[0].usertype,
                     district_code: rows[0].district_code,
                     subdistrict_code: rows[0].subdistrict_code,
                     project: "HORTI"
                     },'secret', {
                     expiresIn: '2h'
                  });
                  return callback(null,[{
                     success: 'Welcome',
                     token: JWTToken
                 }]);
               });
            }
            else {
               return callback({status: false, failed: 'Unauthorized Access'});
           }
        });
     }
     else { return callback({status: false})}
   });
}

my encrypt decrypt code
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
exports.decrypt= function ( passphrase , encrypted_json_string) {
    const obj_json = JSON.parse(encrypted_json_string);
    const encrypted = obj_json.cipherText;
    const salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(obj_json.salt);
    const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(obj_json.iv);
    const key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(passphrase, salt, {
        hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA512,
        keySize: 64 / 8,
        iterations: 10000,
    });
    let decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, {iv: iv});
    let a = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    return a;
}
exports.encrypt= function(passphrase, json_string) {
    const salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(256);
    const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
    const key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(passphrase, salt, {
        hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA512,
        keySize: 64 / 8,
        iterations: 10000,
    });
    const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(json_string, key, {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        keySize: 256,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
        iv: iv,
    });
    return JSON.stringify({
        cipherText: encrypted.toString(),
        salt: salt.toString(),
        iv: iv.toString(),
    });
}

HERE im sending data in api
{   
    "password": "{"cipherText":"XXXXXXXXXX","salt":"XXXX","iv":"XX"}",
    "user_id": "1234",
    "usertype": "1"
}

i want to fix password replay. please help
provide a way to fix the password replay with an example.

you have to generate a random challenge and send it with the login request. From the server, you must validate the challenge the client sent before processing the request. Once the request is completed (it doesn't matter whether login is a success or failure), You have to blacklist the challenge to block replayed requests.
